# Azure Video Analyzer for Media - ARM_ACCOUNT_MUST_BE_MANAGED_BY_ARM

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-video-indexer

I have followed this tutorial to create an unlimited account: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-for-media-docs/create-video-analyzer-for-media-account

Now, I have 4 new resources in my Azure Portal:

- Managed Identity
- Media Service
- Storage Account
- Video Analyzer for Media

Then, I created a new subscription in this page: https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/product#product=authorization

Everything seems to be ok, but when I try to call the API to get an Account Access Token I get this error:

```
{
    "ErrorType": "ARM_ACCOUNT_MUST_BE_MANAGED_BY_ARM",
    "Message": "You can only use the ARM management API for management calls on accounts created on ARM. <a href=\"https://aka.ms/avam-arm-docs\">Learn more</a>. Trace id: 'c99f6cd7-8577-4f3f-b7b8-58a504e60b7d'."
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see sample in there how to generate access token for AVAM ARM account:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-video-indexer/tree/master/ApiUsage/ArmBased

(look at Program.cs)

Comment: Thanks! I used that code and works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You should use ARM APIs in order to get access token for you account.
Please see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-for-media-docs/create-video-analyzer-for-media-account#management-api
You can generate access token using Azure Portal thorugh your resources.

If you have any further question please let me know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, the token generated from Azure Portal works like expected, but is valid for just one hour. How can I generate new tokens from code no from Azure Portal?